# Fatal error: Call to undefined function webform_menu_load()

Tags: webforms

I tried to use a Drupal project which was previously developed by another person.
I have imported the database as well.

When I try to run the website, I get this error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function webform_menu_load()

I tried to remove progressively all the modules I have, but it's not working.

Does anyone know how to resolve this?

Comment: webform_menu_load() is a function of the webform module.  Is the webform module installed?

Comment: Removing modules doesn't resolve the issue, as the issue is that Drupal doesn't find a module.

Comment: Have you made sure that the Webform module folder and files are present under sites/all/modules?
Have you made sure that Webform is enabled on the Modules admin page?
Have you cleared the caches on the Performance page?
Have you run update.php?